# How to center contact form and put certain inputs on certain lines

Tags: html, css

I have got a basic contact form, but when i try to customise it with css, then it won't customise, as I want the form in the middle and I wish Name, Email & age on the top line and Subject and select category on the section line, with the big text box on the last line and the button at the bottom, but the form won't customise for some reason. Have i done something wrong?

I have tried numinous css inputs like float, text align, margin-left, padding-left and even display. I have search the internet and looked for tutorial and even tried the tutorial, but still nothing.

My HTM Code is:

```
<li><button id="mouthoff-button">Mouthoff</button><div id="mouthoff-modal" class="mouthoff-modal"><div class="mouthoff-modal-content"><div class="mouthoff-modal-header"><span class="mouthoff-close">&times;</span></div><div class="mouthoff-modal-body"><h3>MOUTHOFF - TELL US WHAT'S ON YOUR MIND</h3>
                    <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won't reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we're always happy to have a look at what you have to say.<br><p>If you have a technical issue that you'd like to report, <a href="#">please contact our Support Team</a>.</p>
                    <form>
                      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                      <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="13" max="100">
                      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                      <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
                      </select>
                      <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea>
                      <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </form>
```

My CSS is

```
.mouthoff-modal-body input[type=text], input[type=email] {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 150px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I know their is not a lot of CSS, but I have tried mostly everything that I could think off.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the rest of the page is valid and you've closed all those divs i'm not sure, but perhaps give the form tag an id to style it by?

```
<form id="mouthoff.form">
```

Comment: and if i close the div just before the form, then the form does not end up in the modal :/

Comment: yah, i didn't mean before the styling.. see where they are closed in hassan's answer. please update your question with any new findings and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Be Aware of the order of files and libraries that You have imported, any css or js or jquery libraries, They tend to overwrite your code.

link your css file in the end of head tag after all files.

place your js file at the bottom of the file after all files you have imported.

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few CSS changes. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.mouthoff-modal-body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px;
}

.mouthoff-modal-body input,
.mouthoff-modal-body select {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}

.mouthoff-modal-body textarea {
 display: block;
 resize: none;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="mouthoff-button">Mouthoff</button>
<div id="mouthoff-modal" class="mouthoff-modal">
<div class="mouthoff-modal-content">
<div class="mouthoff-modal-header">
 <span class="mouthoff-close">×</span>
</div>
 <div class="mouthoff-modal-body">
<h3>MOUTHOFF - TELL US WHAT'S ON YOUR MIND</h3>
                <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won't reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we're always happy to have a look at what you have to say.<br></p><p>If you have a technical issue that you'd like to report, <a href="#">please contact our Support Team</a>.</p>
                <form>
                   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                   <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="13" max="100">
                   <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                   <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                     <option value="">Select Category</option>
                     <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
                   </select>
                   <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea>
                   <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                 </form>
    
  
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```css
        form {
            text-align: center;
        }
        form * {
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
        <button id="mouthoff-button">Mouthoff</button><div id="mouthoff-modal" class="mouthoff-modal"><div class="mouthoff-modal-content"><div class="mouthoff-modal-header"><span class="mouthoff-close">&times;</span></div><div class="mouthoff-modal-body"><h3>MOUTHOFF - TELL US WHAT'S ON YOUR MIND</h3>
            <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won't reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we're always happy to have a look at what you have to say.<br><p>If you have a technical issue that you'd like to report, <a href="#">please contact our Support Team</a>.</p>
            <form>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="13" max="100"><br>
              <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
              </select><br>
              <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea><br>
              <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
```